# How decrease space between scales divs in Css

Tags: css, scale, margin, css-transforms, space

I have scaled down star shape in css but cannot decrese the space between each of them.

here is the code.

// html
5 divs in a container

//css

container with flex property to center and space-around property

```
.star {
/*code*/
    transform: rotate(35deg) scale(.15);
  }
```

[image: output]

so accoding to the above code the stars are scaled but the space between them as not reduce.
Note that here i have used
Note that i have applied a transform scale to reduce the size but i cannot change the space between them in flex box.

Please help me scale down the div without affecting the space around it.
please refer the image attched to know what im saying here.

I am trying to fit them inside the container, but its clearly going out

Comment: Only your CSS is showing. Can you pop the HTML on too please?

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?